# Feature access not support symbology based in multiple fields in sharing service (ArcGIS, ArcGIS Desktop, ERROR 00085)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, symbology, arcgis-10.4

[image]

Error 00085 : Layer uses an unsupported renderer

In the service publication -> Capabilities -> feature access checked! : does not support symbology based in multiple fields!

Is there an approach to symbolize with the use of multiple columns? Avoiding the creation of a combination column between the fields concerned?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Your example seems to indicate two columns for symbology Type and ETAT.

Likely the simplest method is to break your single layer out in to multiple layers based on one of the columns.  Use a definition Query on each layer that represents the values in one of the columns.  Then use the simple single field symbology on each layer based on the other column. Sadly ESRI doesn't currently allow symbology from multiple columns in Feature services (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012919)